# Anchor Element Download Attribute in Safari vs Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, mozilla

I have a question regarding the download attribute in safari. Let's say you have a site, `siteA.com`, and it has a link with `aws.presignedulr.com` as `href`.

```
<a href="aws.presignedurl.com" download>Click file</a>
```

Per mozilla docs, the download attribute only works if it's `same-origin`. In safari, if you click the link, it opens the file but it doesn't download to your computer. Which is expected since it's not `same-origin`. However, in chrome the link gets clicked and it downloads the file.

It seems chrome doesn't have this issues, it downloads fine.

Now let's say in safari, if the href URL is `href="siteA.com/downloads/text.csv"`, whose base url is the same as the host name, `siteA.com`, then the file gets downloaded because of `same-origin`; this can be tested using this [URL](https://copylists.com/geography/list-all-us-states/), scroll down and click on `download csv file` link. You'll notice the download link base url is the same as the host name.

I was wondering why chrome doesn't have this issue, even the host domain and the download link are different; I haven't tested for firefox. Could this be a safari/browser behavior or user settings?

Your help will be appreciated, thanks :)